# How To Change Image Sizes in Racket

Tags: image, url, scheme, racket, htdp

I am making a game using `racket` and need a background  `bitmap` image. But the image I have selected is too big. How do I change the size? What I have:

```
(bitmap/url "http://www.example.com/")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import this package:

```
(require htdp/image)
```

And use the [shrink](http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/image.html#%28def._%28%28lib._htdp/image..rkt%29._shrink%29%29) procedures defined in that package.

**EDIT :**

As has been pointed out in the comments, [2htdp/image](http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html) would be a better alternative:

```
(require 2htdp/image)
```

Take a look at the [scale](http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html#%28def._%28%28lib._2htdp/image..rkt%29._scale%29%29) procedure.

Comment: The htdp/image is deprecated, so it's probably better to recommend the `scale` function in the 2htdp/image library.