# How to add Modules to WeScheme

Tags: module, scheme, racket, wescheme

I am currently working on a program, that uses images and need to add the module mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318208/how-to-change-image-sizes-in-racket/10318391#10318391)

```
(require 2htdp/image)
```

I come up the the error

```
I see a require of the module 2htdp/image,
but I don't yet know what this module is.
```

How do I solve this? I have no idea how to make WeScheme know what a module is. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`2htdp/image`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html) is part of the How to Design Programs teachpacks that come with [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/), if you need it you should use Racket as your Scheme interpreter.

Comment: So it will work with racket, but not wescheme? Isn't wescheme just a extension if you will of racket?

Comment: AFAIK they're separate projects, WeScheme gets compiled to JavaScript. I don't think you can use modules from one in the other without porting some of the codebase first

Comment: Ah, I learn a new thing everyday, how would I go about using Racket as my Scheme interpreter

Comment: You can download DrRacket at: http://racket-lang.org.  It's a desktop application.  Afterwards, see something like: http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2012-April/051624.html to get DrRacket running.

(Aside: WeScheme is my baby.  It does not currently support enough of Racket to get most of the interesting modules, such as `2htdp/image`, working yet.  WeScheme includes our own implementation of many of the `2htdp/image` primitives.)

Comment: @dyoo but what is the wescheme equivelant of scale?

Comment: The `scale` function should be in WeScheme as part of its base language.

Comment: @dyoo Ah yes... Sorry I didn't have access to it then

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, it looks like you meant to write `2htdp/image`, but you wrote `htdp2/image` instead.  Note the different location of the `2`.